# How to load Mysql data into html select element when a different select element option is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

Please am facing a crucial issue in my ajax request code recently.
Issue: am trying to load a data from mysql database(using php) when an html selection tag option is clicked in my program which is to load received data from the database into another html selection tag. thus it turned out to work in Firefox browser but doesn't in other browsers(e.g chrome, safari and opera). for more clarification i will leave my code below. Thank you.

```
ajax:
get_service_categories_ready_for_booking_selection();
function get_service_categories_ready_for_booking_selection() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "query.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {getServicesCategoriesReadyForBooking:1},
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#display-services-categories-options").html(data);
            console.log(status)
        }
    });
}

$("body").on("click", "#service_cate_options", function () {
    var cate_id = $(this).attr("s_cate_id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "query.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {getServicesReadyForUsingCategoriesBooking:1, cate_id:cate_id},
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#display-services").html(data);
            console.log(status)
            // load_selected_service_cost();
        }
    });
});

PHP:
function fetch_services_based_on_selected_category(){
    include("includes/db.php");
    $output = "";
    $cate_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cate_id"]);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE `cate_id`='".$cate_id."'";
    $run = $con->query($query);
    $output .= "<option>Select your choice of service</option>";
    if ($run->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $run->fetch_array()) {
            $service_id = $row["id"];
            $service_name = $row["title"];
            $service_charge = $row["cost"];

            $output .= "<option id='service_options' service_id='".$service_id."'>".$service_name."</option>";
        }
    }else{
            $output .= "<option>We're currently out of services</option>";
        }
    return $output;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" align="right">Select Categories*</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <select class="form-control form-control-sm cate_name" id="display-services-categories-options">
                                    <!-- <option>Categories Options</option> -->
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3" align="right">Select Service</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <select class="form-control form-control-sm service_name" id="display-services">
                                    <!-- <option>Services Options</option> -->
                                </select>
                                <div class="return-info" style="font-size: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
                                <div class="error-info text-danger" style="font-size: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML and the PHP where you call the `fetch_services_based_on_selected_category` function please? Your code is potentially open to `SQL Injection` attacks also!

Comment: `service_id` is NOT a valid attribute to add to any HTML element - consider using a `dataset` attribute instead - such as `data-service_id=X` etc

Comment: Any ID used ( ie: `service_options` ) MUST be unique

Comment: Yes every selection option has it unique ID

Comment: `$output .= "<option id='service_options'` suggests otherwise!

Comment: *suggests otherwise!, thus it doesn't still work even when I tried changing the element ID into something else.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your**

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm cate_name" id="display-services-categories-options">
```

**Change it to:**

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm cate_name" id="display-services-categories-options" onChange="get_service_categories_ready_for_booking_selection()">
```

**You can also pass;**

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm cate_name" id="display-services-categories-options" onChange="get_service_categories_ready_for_booking_selection(this.value)">
```

Then control it in the get_service_categories_ready_for_booking_selection() function. If you can include parameter in the function, update your function like this;

```
function get_service_categories_ready_for_booking_selection(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "query.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {getServicesCategoriesReadyForBooking:id},
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#display-services-categories-options").html(data);
            console.log(status)
        }
    });
}
```

make sure the url path is correct. Then this should work fine! Please make as answered if this is what you are looking for.

**Also:** Check this ID: "#service_cate_options" is not referring to anything. I guess you want to refer to one of the select options

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fellow associates for all contributions, although none of the answer provided above could fixed the problem, thus this did:

HTML SELECT ELEMENT:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm cate_name" id="display-services-categories-options">
</select>
```

**jquery Before:**

```
$("body").on("click", "#service_cate_options", function () {
    var cate_id = $(this).attr("s_cate_id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "query.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {getServicesReadyForUsingCategoriesBooking:1, cate_id:cate_id},
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#display-services").html(data);
            console.log(status)
            // load_selected_service_cost();
        }
    });
});
```

**jquery After:**

```
$("select.cate_name").change(function () {
    var cate_id = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "query.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {getServicesReadyForUsingCategoriesBooking:1, cate_id:cate_id},
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#display-services").html(data);
            console.log(status)
            // load_selected_service_cost();
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP Before:**

```
function fetch_services_based_on_selected_category(){
    include("includes/db.php");
    $output = "";
    $cate_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cate_id"]);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE `cate_id`='".$cate_id."'";
    $run = $con->query($query);
    $output .= "<option>Select your choice of service</option>";
    if ($run->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $run->fetch_array()) {
            $service_id = $row["id"];
            $service_name = $row["title"];
            $service_charge = $row["cost"];

            $output .= "<option id='service_options' **service_id**='".$service_id."'>".$service_name."</option>";
        }
    }else{
            $output .= "<option>We're currently out of services</option>";
        }
    return $output;
}
```

**PHP After:**

```
function fetch_services_based_on_selected_category(){
    include("includes/db.php");
    $output = "";
    $cate_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cate_id"]);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE `cate_id`='".$cate_id."'";
    $run = $con->query($query);
    $output .= "<option>Select your choice of service</option>";
    if ($run->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $run->fetch_array()) {
            $service_id = $row["id"];
            $service_name = $row["title"];
            $service_charge = $row["cost"];

            $output .= "<option id='service_options' **value**='".$service_id."'>".$service_name."</option>";
        }
    }else{
            $output .= "<option>We're currently out of services</option>";
        }
    return $output;
}
```

In php code change the self created attribute name(what ever your attribute was) to value which the select option ID is assigned to.

for more details: [https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/how+to+get+value+from+select+option+using+input+name+in+jquery][1]